# Creating patches for training a neural network from images collected from GEE JS Web API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to train a Neural network with the images downloaded from GEE. I am trying to export my image from GEE, using JS Web API. Here I am using Sentinel-2(COPERNICUS/S2_SR) images. I performed some classification on it, and now trying to export it.
When exporting the image as below:

```
 Export.image.toDrive({
    image: im8.select('B2','B3','B4','classification').toFloat(),
    description: 'PatchesExport_com',
    fileNamePrefix: 'Image_',
    scale: 10,
    folder: 'myNewData',
    region: im.geometry().bounds(), // .geometry().bounds() needed for multipolygon
});
```

And reading the layers using the python package **rasterio**, I am able to see my bands properly.
[image: showing the classified image]

But, the problem is coming when I am trying to create small patches of this layered image. So, I tried to separately download the classified layer. Code for this

```
import rasterio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_file = "../classified.tif"
sat_data = rasterio.open(image_file)

#
c= sat_data2.read()  #Reading the classified band

#
fig = plt.imshow(c)
plt.show()
```

This gave me the image as below:
[image]

And, to my surprise, my composite image of bands RGB, now shows as below:

[image]

What is the issue? If this cannot get solved, can I create patches from the RGB+classified image?
Please guide.

Comment: Please share youre python code that raised the TypeError. Also, how did you try to create the patches?

Comment: @Ofir I have updated the question with the python code, that raised the error.

Comment: @Ofir My first thought was to create small patches of images, like shown here: https://towardsdatascience.com/is-cnn-equally-shiny-on-mid-resolution-satellite-data-9e24e68f0c08 . Therefore to match with this execution, I tried to collect data separately.